# How map unit affects the caption size in the label in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, map-unit

I tried to make a the label caption size adjusted relatively to the map scale.
It worked, more or less, when I set the size into map unit.
I set them to `0.1`, and when I zoom out the caption size get smaller

[image]

And when I zoom in it get bigger

[image]

However I cannot understand what is the *"map point"* logic, or in other words how does it work.

And one more question: is there a better way to adjusted the caption size and force them to always be inside the polygon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `points` unit represents a constant size for the label on the screen, more or less the same as millimeters or pixels. Regardless of the map scale, a label of 10 points will be 10 points tall (let's ignore font sizing subtleties). It is your responsibility to hide the labels - or use a different size - beyond given map scales. For instance, labeling continents, you probably will keep the same size all the time, though if you label streets you will not want a size 10 label at any scale.

The map unit is the opposite. A label of size 1 (degree, meters, you name it) will always be of size 1 on the map, so the closer you are to scale 1:1 the bigger it is on your screen, and the more you zoom out the smaller the label is, still on your screen.

If you want finer control of a label that gets smaller as you zoom out and bigger as you zoom in, you would have to select the `points` unit, so the reference size is always the same on the screen, but you would also dynamically set the size in function of the scale, something like `10000000  /@map_scale` (of course it depends on your data and you may want a non-linear scaling).

[image: Label by map scale]

To answer you second question, you can instruct QGIS to hide labels that are not fully contained in their feature

[image: Label inside feature]