# Specific label size in composer QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to make a specific map in 1:1500 and 1:2000 scale on A2 paper but the label height should be 2.5 mm in composer.

Is there a correlations between label size in "map units" or "points" to produce that specific size in composer.

All this time I just doing Trial and Error method.

Comment: can you not specify mm as the unit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use map units you could calculate the conversion.
If you have your project units in meters. In a 1:1000 scale, 1 mm equals to 1 m. So if you want your label at 5 mm in a 1:1000 scale you could use map units and size to 5 m.

It is a conversion factor. And your factors are the scale and the conversion between your units. In this case millimeters to meters.

Comment: Thank you @Albert I will try this method later. I think it is makes sense. Do you have any idea about "Point" unit?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243881/34877
I think it will clarify your doubts